# Can i set SSAS multidimensional model data source a database in a SQL Server linked server?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, linked-server

I have a SQL Server linked server called `[HJNSDATAENG.DW]`. I have created a SSAS multidimensional project called `rh_dw`.

I want to set as my SSAS project's data source the database [warehouse] located in `[HJNSDATAENG.DW]` linked server.

Is this possible? If yes what are the different steps?

Comment: Have you read [SSAS's documentation on creating data-sources in SSAS Multidimensional projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/create-a-data-source-ssas-multidimensional?view=asallproducts-allversions)? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes I did! I am talking about db in a linked server here. The linked-servers in my SQL Server instance doesn't appear in SAS Connection Manager

Comment: You would likely have to create new views that query the linked server - those views would then be available in within your Data Source View.  Your data-source definitely can't be set directly to a linked server - the primary database for the data-source needs to be a local database on the server that your project connects to.